# Pygame, how to make collision when the player hits its head into a block (tile)

Tags: python, pygame

I dont know how to make the collision,when the player hits its head into a block.
When it hits the block from the bottom with its head, then its going to "teleport" up.
And the same thing happens when the player hits the block horizontally, so if `self.x` or `self.player_rect.x` hits the block, it will teleport the player up.

So basically, if the player hits its head into a block, then the player needs to fall down.
And if it hits it horizontally, so players X, then player needs to stop moving.

I tried doing this:

```
#COLLISION WITH BLOCKS
for tile in self.tile_list:
    if tile[1].colliderect(self.player_rect):
        if self.player_rect.y > 0:
            self.player_rect.bottom = tile[1].top
            self.y = self.player_rect.y
        elif self.player_rect.y < 0:
            self.player_rect.top = tile[1].bottom
            self.y = self.player_rect.y
```

But didnt help. `tile_list` is a list where tiles are actually saved in. Im looping through that list to check all the tiles(blocks) and make a collision. However my player can stand on a tile(block), but i would like to make it better, so I just want my player to dont teleport when it hits the tile's.y or x.

main.py:

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
import os

from pygame import key
from mapdata import game_map_data

#ASSETS
GRASS_IMAGE = pg.image.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pygame-tilemap\1.11.2022\assets\platform.jpg')
sky = pg.image.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pygame-tilemap\1.11.2022\assets\sky.png')
CONTINUE = True

#CONSTANT VARIABLES
#WIDTH;HEIGHT
WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 598
PLAYER_WIDTH = 20
PLAYER_HEIGHT = 20
#COLORS
COLOR_DARKBLUE = 'darkblue'
COLOR_RED = 'red'
#WINDOW
WINDOW = pg.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT))

sky = pg.transform.scale(sky,(800,599))

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,jumpRange):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpRange = jumpRange

    def Draw(self):
        self.player = pg.image.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pygame-tilemap\1.11.2022\assets\player.png')
        self.player = pg.transform.scale(self.player,(PLAYER_WIDTH,PLAYER_HEIGHT))
        self.player_rect = self.player.get_rect()
        WINDOW.blit(self.player,dest=(self.x,self.y))
        self.player_rect.x = self.x
        self.player_rect.y = self.y

    #COLLISION WITH BLOCKS
    for tile in self.tile_list:
        if tile[1].colliderect(self.player_rect):
            if self.player_rect.y > 0:
                self.player_rect.bottom = tile[1].top
                self.y = self.player_rect.y
            elif self.player_rect.y < 0:
                self.player_rect.top = tile[1].bottom
                self.y = self.player_rect.y
                
    def handle_keys(self,speed,vel_y):
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        self.speed = speed
        self.vel_y = vel_y
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            if CONTINUE == True:
                self.x += speed
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            if CONTINUE == True:
                self.x -= speed


    def jump(self,jumpRange):
        if self.isJump == True:
            if self.jumpRange >= -11:
                neg = 1
                if self.jumpRange < 0:
                    neg = -1
                self.y -= self.jumpRange**2 * 0.1 * neg
                self.jumpRange -= 1
            else:
                self.isJump = False
                self.jumpRange = jumpRange

    ###########
    ##TILEMAP##
    ###########

    def tile(self,data,tile_size,img_size):
        self.tile_list = []

        #SAVING TILES IN A LIST

        row_count = 0
        self.tile_size = tile_size
        self.img_size = img_size

        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    self.rect_img = img.get_rect()
                    self.rect_img.x = col_count * tile_size
                    self.rect_img.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img,self.rect_img)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1

    #DRAWING TILES FROM THE LIST
    def draw_tile(self):
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            WINDOW.blit(tile[0], tile[1])



#FPS
clock = pg.time.Clock()


game_map_data = game_map_data


#PLAYER
player = Player(x=30,y=500,width=PLAYER_WIDTH,height=PLAYER_HEIGHT,jumpRange=11)


img_size = 17
img = pg.transform.scale(GRASS_IMAGE,(img_size,img_size))
gamemap = player.tile(game_map_data,tile_size=17,img_size=20)



while True:
    FPS = 60
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

    
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                # Start to jump by setting isJump to True.
                player.isJump = True

    SKY_POSITION = (0,0)

    WINDOW.blit(sky,SKY_POSITION)
    player.draw_tile()
    player.jump(jumpRange=11)
    player.Draw()
    player.handle_keys(speed=3,vel_y=3)
    pg.display.update()
    pg.display.flip()
```

If u want to test the code, create 2 files, mapdata.py and main.py, and change photos(textures)

mapdata.py:

```
game_map_data = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when working with pygame, it is much easier if you use pygame sprite class :

You might need this function for collision.

```
# this function is used when there is one object collides with many objects
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,power_pellets,false):
    # do something
```

Another function that you may use is: groupcollide(...

```
#this function is used when a group of objects collide with other group of objects.
collide_with_wall = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(smart_ghost, walls, False, False)
if collide_with_wall:
    # do something
```

to use pygame sprite, you need to inherit it from a pygam sprite class

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image_origin = pacman_img  # use this technique when rotate many times
        self.image_origin.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image = self.image_origin.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()  # second mandatory
def update(self): # 
# do something here
```

Go to this youtube to learn more about collision with pygame sprite: https://youtu.be/Eltz-XJMxuU

Trust me, this channel is really good for designing games; the tutor also suggests where you can get free resources (game images, icons, sound effects, and so on...)